# Wrap javascript fetch to add custom functionality

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, fetch

I would like to know if it is possible to do this, because I'm not sure if I'm wrong or if it isn't possible. Basically, what I want to do is to create a wrap function for native `fetch` javascript function. This wrap function would implement token validation process, requesting a new `accessToken` if the one given is expired and requesting again the desired resource. This is what I've reached until now:

`customFetch.js`

```
// 'url' and 'options' parameters are used strictely as you would use them in fetch. 'authOptions' are used to configure the call to refresh the access token
window.customFetch = (url, options, authOptions) => {

    const OPTIONS = {
        url: '',
        unauthorizedRedirect: '',
        storage: window.sessionStorage,
        tokenName: 'accessToken'
    }

    // Merge options passed by user with the default auth options
    let opts = Object.assign({}, OPTIONS, authOptions);

    // Try to update 'authorizarion's header in order to send always the proper one to the server
    options.headers = options.headers || {};
    options.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${opts.storage.getItem(opts.tokenName)}`;

    // Actual server request that user wants to do.
    const request = window.fetch(url, options)
        .then((d) => {
            if (d.status === 401) {
                // Unauthorized
                console.log('not authorized');
                return refreshAccesToken();
            }
            else {
                return d.json();
            }
        });

    // Auxiliar server call to get refresh the access token if it is expired. Here also check if the 
    // cookie has expired and if it has expired, then we should redirect to other page to login again in
    // the application.
    const refreshAccesToken = () => {
        window.fetch(opts.url, {
            method: 'get',
            credentials: 'include'
        }).then((d) => {
            // For this example, we can omit this, we can suppose we always receive the access token
            if (d.status === 401) {
                // Unauthorized and the cookie used to validate and refresh the access token has expired. So we want to login in to the app again
                window.location.href = opts.unauthorizedRedirect;
            }

            return d.json();
        }).then((json) => {
            const jwt = json.token;
            if (jwt) {
                // Store in the browser's storage (sessionStorage by default) the refreshed token, in order to use it on every request
                opts.storage.setItem(opts.tokenName, jwt);
                console.log('new acces token: ' + jwt);

                // Re-send the original request when we have received the refreshed access token.
                return window.customFetch(url, options, authOptions);
            }
            else {
                console.log('no token has been sent');
                return null;
            }
        });
    }

    return request;
}
```

`consumer.js`

```
const getResourcePrivate = () => {
        const url = MAIN_URL + '/resource';
        customFetch(url, {
            method: 'get'
        },{
            url: AUTH_SERVER_TOKEN,
            unauthorizedRedirect: AUTH_URI,
            tokenName: TOKEN_NAME
        }).then((json) => {
            const resource = json ? json.resource : null;
            if (resource) {
                console.log(resource);
            }
            else {
                console.log('No resource has been provided.');
            }
        });
}
```

I'll try to explain a little better the above code: I want to make transparent for users the token validation, in order to let them just worry about to request the resource they want. This approach is working fine when the `accessToken` is still valid, because the `return request` instruction is giving to the consumer the promise of the `fetch` request.

Of course, when the `accessToken` has expired and we request a new one to `auth` server, this is not working. The token is refreshed and the private resource is requested, but the `consumer.js` doesn't see it.

For this last scenario, is it possible to modify the flow of the program, in order to refresh the `accessToken` and perform the server call to get the private resource again? The consumer shouldn't realize about this process; in both cases (`accessToken` is valid and `accessToken` has expired and has been refreshed) the `consumer.js` should get the private requested resource in its `then` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, finally I've reached a solution. I've tried to resolve it using a `Promise` and it has work. Here is the approach for `customFetch.js` file:

```
window.customFetch = (url, options, authOptions) => {

    const OPTIONS = {
        url: '',
        unauthorizedRedirect: '',
        storage: window.sessionStorage,
        tokenName: 'accessToken'
    }

    // Merge options passed by user with the default auth options
    let opts = Object.assign({}, OPTIONS, authOptions);

    const requestResource = (resolve) => {
        // Try to update 'authorizarion's header in order to send always the proper one to the server
        options.headers = options.headers || {};
        options.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${opts.storage.getItem(opts.tokenName)}`;

        window.fetch(url, options)
            .then((d) => {
                if (d.status === 401) {
                    // Unauthorized
                    console.log('not authorized');
                    return refreshAccesToken(resolve);
                }
                else {
                    resolve(d.json());
                }
            });
    }

    // Auxiliar server call to get refresh the access token if it is expired. Here also check if the 
    // cookie has expired and if it has expired, then we should redirect to other page to login again in
    // the application.
    const refreshAccesToken = (resolve) => {
        window.fetch(opts.url, {
            method: 'get',
            credentials: 'include'
        }).then((d) => {
            if (d.status === 401) {
                // Unauthorized
                window.location.href = opts.unauthorizedRedirect;
            }

            return d.json();
        }).then((json) => {
            const jwt = json.token;
            if (jwt) {
                // Store in the browser's storage (sessionStorage by default) the refreshed token, in order to use it on every request
                opts.storage.setItem(opts.tokenName, jwt);
                console.log('new acces token: ' + jwt);

                // Re-send the original request when we have received the refreshed access token.
                requestResource(resolve);
            }
            else {
                console.log('no token has been sent');
                return null;
            }
        });
    }

    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        requestResource(resolve);
    });

    return promise;
}
```

Basically, I've created a `Promise` and I've called inside it to the function which calls to server to get the resource. I've modified a little the `request`(now called `requestResource`) and `refreshAccessToken` in order to make them parametrizable functions. And I've passed to them the `resolve` function in order to "resolve" any function once I've received the new token.

Probably the solution can be improved and optimized, but as first approach, it is working as I expected, so I think it's a valid solution.

**EDIT**: As @Dennis has suggested me, I made a mistake in my initial approach. I just had to return the promise inside the `refreshAccessToken` function, and it would worked fine. This is how the `customFetch.js` file should look (which is more similar to the code I first posted. In fact, I've just added a `return` instruction inside the function, although removing the start and end brackets would work too):

```
// 'url' and 'options' parameters are used strictely as you would use them in fetch. 'authOptions' are used to configure the call to refresh the access token
window.customFetch = (url, options, authOptions) => {

    const OPTIONS = {
        url: '',
        unauthorizedRedirect: '',
        storage: window.sessionStorage,
        tokenName: 'accessToken'
    }

    // Merge options passed by user with the default auth options
    let opts = Object.assign({}, OPTIONS, authOptions);

    // Try to update 'authorizarion's header in order to send always the proper one to the server
    options.headers = options.headers || {};
    options.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${opts.storage.getItem(opts.tokenName)}`;

    // Actual server request that user wants to do.
    const request = window.fetch(url, options)
        .then((d) => {
            if (d.status === 401) {
                // Unauthorized
                console.log('not authorized');
                return refreshAccesToken();
            }
            else {
                return d.json();
            }
        });

    // Auxiliar server call to get refresh the access token if it is expired. Here also check if the 
    // cookie has expired and if it has expired, then we should redirect to other page to login again in
    // the application.
    const refreshAccesToken = () => {
        return window.fetch(opts.url, {
            method: 'get',
            credentials: 'include'
        }).then((d) => {
            // For this example, we can omit this, we can suppose we always receive the access token
            if (d.status === 401) {
                // Unauthorized and the cookie used to validate and refresh the access token has expired. So we want to login in to the app again
                window.location.href = opts.unauthorizedRedirect;
            }

            return d.json();
        }).then((json) => {
            const jwt = json.token;
            if (jwt) {
                // Store in the browser's storage (sessionStorage by default) the refreshed token, in order to use it on every request
                opts.storage.setItem(opts.tokenName, jwt);
                console.log('new acces token: ' + jwt);

                // Re-send the original request when we have received the refreshed access token.
                return window.customFetch(url, options, authOptions);
            }
            else {
                console.log('no token has been sent');
                return null;
            }
        });
    }

    return request;
}
```

Comment: Oh, I guess I'm too late then :D I wanted to suggest removing one set of brackets here `const refreshAccesToken = () => window.fetch(...);` This way `refreshAccesToken` should return a promise, instead of `undefined` and everything should be working fine

Comment: @Dennis you are right!! Y made a mistake in that function and I forgot to return the promise. I've tried and it works fine, so I'll edit my answer in order to add your approach too, which was even more close to my inital solution.